# How to use libclang in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, libclang

I want to use the libclang library included with Xcode to do some simple source code parsing.

This is how I do it.

1. Figure out the libclang.dylib using `echo`xcode-select --print-path`/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib`
2. Copy the libclang.dylib file to my project folder.
3. Add it to a clean Xcode project (a Cocoa Application one).
4. Build and run the app

The built process runs fine but the app crash on start up with this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClassStructureAnalyzer-cthpbscauprydagysmerutpnhpua/Build/Products/Debug/ClassStructureAnalyzer.app/Contents/MacOS/ClassStructureAnalyzer
  Reason: image not found
```

Adding the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib` to the runpath doesn't solve the problem.

I understand that this question may have been asked many times, but after googling for the whole day, I haven't figure out the answer yet :(

Thanks in advance!